# Using a function as an array value which returns a result

Tags: php, arrays, lambda, xml-parsing, anonymous

I am trying to process an xml file using a function as an array value which returns a result, for example:

```
$StartTagsArray = [      
    'product1' => getValue($attribute){ return $result = $attribute * 2; },     
];     

$attr = $xml->getAttribute('w:val');
$result = $StartTagsArray[$xml->name];   
echo($result);
```

Unfortunately I am struggling with this, experiencing various errors, but at no point am I able to access and display the returned value.  I have tried $attr as a global within the function. I have tried using the GLOBALS array, passing $attr as a reference with the function, &$attr. Using  "call_user_func()", and using various closures such as:-

```
‘product1' => getValue($attr, function() use( &$var)){ return $var * 2;    }
```

In fact I’ve read and tried loads of possible solutions from within stack overflow and within php.net but to no avail. I accept that in my inexperience I am most likely missing something glaringly obvious or not understanding some aspect of arrays/callbacks etc but for the life of me cannot fathom it out.

Can anyone tell me if there’s a way to pass a variable to a function within an array and display/use the returned value?

Thanks

Comment: `$StartTagsArray = [  'product1' => function($attribute){ return $result = $attribute * 2; }, ];  echo $StartTagsArray['product1'](24);`

Answer (score 1):

as [splash commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38550865/using-a-function-as-an-array-value-which-returns-a-result#comment64492930_38550865), use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
<?php
$StartTagsArray = [
    'product1' => function($attribute){ return $attribute * 2; }
];

$attr = 24;

$result = $StartTagsArray['product1']($attr);

echo($result);
```

This prints:

> 48